# What has four letters

Tags: word

What has four letters, sometimes has nine letters, never has five letters, always has six letters, written has seven letters?

Hint

> The answer is true or false

Answer (score 2):

Ahh I guess the answer is

> True

Since those are actually

> Not questions: What has four letters; sometimes has nine letters; never has five letters; always has five letters; and written has seven letters; For example: A-l-w-a-y-s = 6 letters

Comment: Your choice of example is ... ironic?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> True, because all of the statements are correct for the count of letters in each word.

Comment: sorry, i've changed it

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is

> always

because

> this is the only odd one out of the statements you've made: "what" has four letters, "sometimes" has nine letters, "never" has five letters, "always" DOESN'T have five letters, "written" has seven letters.

Comment: Oops, will change that, it's not that